# Sharing books between iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Could someone give me instructions on how to share the books I actually have in my iPhone to my iPad, possibly via WIFI and without connecting the iPad to iTunes.

With music I did it, but not with books. The funny thing is that since the iPad iBooks application display the titles of the collections (eg Technical, Novel, etc.), it doesnt show any books inside them.

Comment: Did you purchase the books through the iBooks store, or some other way?

Comment: No, they are not purchased, they are, for example, pdf's I have received by email and stored in the iBooks application of my iPhone (via open with iBooks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally need to connect the iPad to the iTunes. Then, in my iTunes, I go to the place where I see my books, select them, right click, add to the playlist and select the iPad.
I think that the confusion comes for refering to a list of books as a playlist (which I think is more addecuate for music); but I is just an opinion.